# json dictionary to bash hash table using readarray

Tags: arrays, bash, jq, ref

First a working example with arrays

```
json_array() {
    local -n array="${1}"
    readarray -d $'\0' -t array < <(
        # Create nul delimited array entry using jq
        jq -cjn --argjson arr "$array" '$arr|map(tostring)|.[]+"\u0000"'
    )
}

> unset arr; arr='["a", "b", "c"]'; json_array arr; echo "${arr[0]} ${arr[1]} ${arr[2]}"
a b c
```

Now I'm trying to do something similar with dict, convert a json dict into a bash associative array

```
json_dict() {
    local -n dict="${1}"
    declare -A hash_table

    append_to_hash_table() {
        shift
        { read -r key;  read -r value; } <<<"$1"
        hash_table+=([$key]="$value")
    }

    readarray -d $'\0' -c 1 -C append_to_hash_table < <(
        # Create nul delimited dict entry using jq
        jq -cjn --argjson d "$dict" '$d|to_entries|map("\(.key)\n\(.value|tostring|@sh)")|.[]+"\u0000"'
    )

    # Here hash_table contain the correct output
    dict=""
    dict="$hash_table"
}

> unset arr; arr='{"a": "aa", "l": "bb", "c": "ccccc"}'; json_dict arr; echo "${arr[@]}"
Nothing
```

It seems `dict="$hash_table"` doesn't correctly update the refname,
How can I make bash `dict` refname point to `hash_table`?

Comment: ob-random-grumble: `-d $'\0'` is **exactly** the same as `-d ''`, except that it's misleading to readers insofar as it implies (falsely) that bash uses Pascal strings that are able to represent NULs as part of their contents.

Comment: `dict="$hash_table"` doesn't work for copying associative arrays. I would strongly suggest building up the output associative array over time.

Comment: BTW, personally, I would use different names for your input and output variables rather than doing an in-place replacement. Less-dangerous failure modes that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for `readarray` here: You can have two separate NUL-delimited `read`s as part of your `while` loop.

See the below answer demonstrated at https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/GrandioseDraftyArguments#main.sh

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' key && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do
  hash_table[$key]=$value
done < <(jq -cjn --argjson d "$arr" \
           '$d | to_entries[] | ( .key, "\u0000", .value, "\u0000")')
```

Putting this into context:

```
json_dict() {
  declare key value in_value="${!1}"
  unset "$1"                   # FIXME: Better to take a $2 for output variable
  declare -g -A "$1"
  declare -n hash_table="$1"
  while IFS= read -r -d '' key && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do
    hash_table[$key]=$value
  done < <(
    jq -cjn --argjson d "$in_value" \
      '$d | to_entries[] | ( .key, "\u0000", .value, "\u0000")'
  )
}
 
arr='{"a": "aa", "l": "bb", "c": "ccccc"}'
json_dict arr
declare -p arr
```

...emits as output:

```
declare -A arr=([a]="aa" [c]="ccccc" [l]="bb" )
```

---

That said, to answer the question *exactly as-asked*, thus using `readarray`:

```
json_dict() {
  declare -a pieces=()

  readarray -d '' pieces < <(
    jq -cjn --argjson d "${!1}" \
      '$d | to_entries[] | ( .key, "\u0000", .value, "\u0000")'
  )

  unset "$1"
  declare -g -A "$1"
  declare -n hash_table="$1"
  set -- "${pieces[@]}"

  while (( $# )); do
    hash_table[$1]=$2
    { shift && shift; } || return
  done
}

arr='{"a": "aa", "l": "bb", "c": "ccccc"}'
json_dict arr
declare -p arr
```

Comment: Why not just `IFS= read -r -d '' key value`?

Comment: @LMC, because hitting the delimiter specified with `-d` ends the whole `read` operation, not just the individual field. Try `IFS= read -r -d '' key value < <(printf '%s\0' one two)` -- it leaves `value` blank.

Comment: Awesome you made the refname work!

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `declare` and have `jq` create the contents using `@sh` for shell conformity?

Indexed array:

```sh
unset arr; arr='["a", "b", "c"]'
declare -a arr="($(jq -r @sh <<< "$arr"))"
```

Associative array:

```sh
unset arr; arr='{"a": "aa", "l": "bb", "c": "ccccc"}'
declare -A arr="($(jq -r 'to_entries[] | @sh "[\(.key)]=\(.value)"' <<< "$arr"))"
```

---

Reacting to an edit request: The above requires the values to be strings (numbers and booleans will kind of work, too), but other structures need to be brought into a stringy format first. In particular, following the request, `@json` could be used to encode an arbitrary JSON content as a string. However, keep in mind that in doing so, the bash array's items will be JSON-encoded, which means that also the simple cases (strings like `aa` from above) will be encoded (e.g. as `"aa"`, including the quotes, as required by JSON). If this is what you want, go for it:

Indexed array with JSON-encoded values:

```sh
unset arr; arr='["a", {}, [null, {"a": true}]]'
declare -a arr="($(jq -r 'map(@json) | @sh' <<< "$arr"))"
```

Associative array with JSON-encoded values:

```sh
unset arr; arr='{"a": "aa", "b": {"l": "bb", "c": "ccccc"}}'
declare -A arr="($(jq -r 'to_entries[] | @sh "[\(.key)]=\(.value | @json)"' <<< "$arr"))"
```

Comment: Good point. In fact, I'm 90% sure I've seen this technique taught on a preexisting Stack Overflow question's answer, which would mean that this question is almost certainly a duplicate.

Comment: Nice very concise, Do you think it is possible without subshells?

Comment: @izissise You need to capture the output of `jq` as `declare` does not read from `stdin` or the like, so using `$(…)` is essential for this solution.